# Activate accordion from image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, imagemap

I'd like to open an accordion from an image map of four internet browsers. So if someone clicks on Firefox, it opens the accordion under the Firefox section. Currently, if someone clicks on one of the four browsers in the image map, it will jump them to the link in the accordion, but it doesn’t open. They then have to click on the link themselves.

I tried the first instruction [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412343/how-to-activate-jquery-accordion-from-an-image-map-href), but I couldn't get it to work. I'm new with javascript so it's possible it's just user error. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the HTML

```
<!--begin accordion-->  

<a id="IE"></a><button class="accordion">Internet Explorer</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>

<a id="Firefox"></a><button class="accordion">Firefox</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>

<a id="Chrome"></a><button class="accordion">Chrome</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>

<a id="Safari"></a><button class="accordion">Safari</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>

<!--end accordion-->`
```

THE MAP

```
 <p class="browers"><img src="_assets/browsers.jpg" alt="Top Internet   Browsers" width="375" height="94" usemap="#Map">
    <map name="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="13,11,82,86" href="#IE" target="_self" alt="Internet Explorer">
    <area shape="rect" coords="104,12,176,85" href="#Firefox" target="_self" alt="Firefox">
    <area shape="rect" coords="198,12,269,85" href="#Chrome" target="_self" alt="Chrome">
    <area shape="rect" coords="288,13,360,83" href="#Safari" target="_self" alt="Safari">
    </map>
  </p>
```

THE SCRIPT

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the onclick attribute to the shapes in the image map.

```
 <p class="browers"><img src="_assets/browsers.jpg" alt="Top Internet   Browsers" width="375" height="94" usemap="#Map">
    <map name="Map">
    <area onclick="activateAccordion('IE')" shape="rect" coords="13,11,82,86" href="#IE" target="_self" alt="Internet Explorer">
    <area onclick="activateAccordion('Firefox')" shape="rect" coords="104,12,176,85" href="#Firefox" target="_self" alt="Firefox">
    <area onclick="activateAccordion('Chrome')" shape="rect" coords="198,12,269,85" href="#Chrome" target="_self" alt="Chrome">
    <area onclick="activateAccordion('Safari')" shape="rect" coords="288,13,360,83" href="#Safari" target="_self" alt="Safari">
    </map>
  </p>
```

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel... I tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't make a difference. Still working on it :).